# button title hides button image iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

i am setting title and image both on button.. but i am facing issue.. my button title overlap the image.

My code is

```
-(void )addImageonbtn:(UIButton *)Button{
 [Button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"drop_bg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
Button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, Button.frame.size.width, 0, 24);
Button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -37, 0, 0);
Button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft ;

Button.layer.borderWidth=1;
Button.layer.borderColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:5/255.0 green:195/255.0 blue:249/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
Button.clipsToBounds=YES;
}
```

How to set image in background of image. Here is image of issue
[image]

Comment: You should create a component having UILabel and UIImageView, where you restrict the width of UILabel to the starting X of UIImageView, it won't overlap.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set background image to solve overlap title issue.

```
 [Button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"drop_bg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you use autolayout and storyboard xcode provide button setting like if you want both text and image in button set semantic force right-to-left

note :  image size must me fit with button text